# Does not create new project in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have found an error in creating a new project in google app engine launcher..i used 32 bit windows

**Error :** path invalid, cannot make project...

**Python version :** Python 2.7.3 windows installer

Edit->preference ---> 
**python path :** C:\Python27\pythonw.exe (same problem arise for python.exe)
**App engine sdk:** C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine
**Editor :** c:/Prgram Files/Windows NT/Accessories/wordpad.exe

i also changed in control panel -> system -> advanced -> environment variables -> PATH **;C:\Python27**

regards,
Gowtham.V

Answer (score 0):

When creating the app, you need to specify a parent directory (where the app is going to be stored).